# Why Puppeteer does not type anything into the text field?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, screen-scraping, puppeteer

I am making an application that needs to synchronize users with a third party site when the user registers or updates the profile on the website. I have made that Puppeteer logs in, it then navigates to the requested page and opens up the modal for the user editing. But, for some reason, it does not fill the information in the fields. The XPath is valid and working, I have also tried with normal querySelector path. It finds the element with both, but it does not update the values.

Here is the HTML which I am trying to effect:

```
<form action="user_process.php?task=edit" method="post" class="ui-modal-form wide" id="edit-user-modal" style="width:840px;">
            <input type="hidden" name="userid" value="8800">
            <fieldset>
                <ul>
                   <li>
                       <label>Name</label>
                       <input type="text" placeholder="Ime i prezime" name="name" value="">
                   </li>
                   <li>
                       <label>User *</label>
                       <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="user" value="">
                   </li>
                   <li>
                       <label>Password *</label>
                       <input type="text" placeholder="Sifra" name="pass" value="">
                   </li>
                   <li>
                       <label>E-mail</label>
                       <input type="text" placeholder="Email adresa" name="email" value="">
                   </li>
                   <li>
                       <label>Support</label>
                       <select name="support">
                           <option value="0">No</option>
                           <option value="1">Yes</option>
                       </select>
                   </li>
                   <li>
                       <label>Servers:</label><br><br>

                       <div class="dataTables_wrapper"><div class="dataTables_filter">Search: <input type="text"></div><table class="data-table" style="">
                       <thead>
                           <tr>
                               <th width="50%" style="text-align:center;vertical-align: middle;" class="sorting_disabled">Server</th>
                               <th width="30%" style="text-align:center;vertical-align: middle;" class="sorting_disabled">IP</th>
                               <th width="10%" style="text-align:center" class="sorting_disabled">WebFTP Access</th>
                               <th width="10%" style="text-align:center" class="sorting_disabled">View FTP Info</th>
                           </tr>
                        </thead>

                        <tbody><tr class="odd">
                                    <td><label style="width: 100%;"><input type="checkbox" class="servercheckbox" style="top:-4px;" name="60203" value="1"> Xtreme COD:MW4</label></td>
                                    <td style="text-align:right"><a target="_blank" href="gp-info.php?id=60203">176.57.142.179:27022</a> </td>
                                    <td style="text-align:center"><input type="checkbox" class="servercheckbox" name="webftp_access[60203]" value="1"> </td>
                                    <td style="text-align:center"><input type="checkbox" class="servercheckbox" name="view_ftpinfo[60203]" value="1"> </td>
                                </tr><tr class="even">
                                    <td><label style="width: 100%;"><input type="checkbox" class="servercheckbox" style="top:-4px;" name="60205" value="1"> FDL</label></td>
                                    <td style="text-align:right"><a target="_blank" href="gp-info.php?id=60205">193.192.58.55:1</a> </td>
                                    <td style="text-align:center"><input type="checkbox" class="servercheckbox" name="webftp_access[60205]" value="1"> </td>
                                    <td style="text-align:center"><input type="checkbox" class="servercheckbox" name="view_ftpinfo[60205]" value="1"> </td>
                                </tr><tr class="odd">
                                    <td><label style="width: 100%;"><input type="checkbox" class="servercheckbox" style="top:-4px;" name="60353" value="1"> Xtreme CW</label></td>
                                    <td style="text-align:right"><a target="_blank" href="gp-info.php?id=60353">193.192.59.233:27025</a> </td>
                                    <td style="text-align:center"><input type="checkbox" class="servercheckbox" name="webftp_access[60353]" value="1"> </td>
                                    <td style="text-align:center"><input type="checkbox" class="servercheckbox" name="view_ftpinfo[60353]" value="1"> </td>
                                </tr></tbody></table></div>
                   </li>
                   <li>
                        <button>Sacuvaj</button>
                   </li>
                </ul>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
```

Puppeteer Codes that I have tried to use:

First variant:

```
try {
        // Wait for the table
        await page.waitForXPath('//table[contains(@class, "data-table")]//tbody//tr//a[contains(text(), "Edit") and contains(@data-user, "TestName") and contains(@data-user, "TestMail@test.com")]')
            .catch(e => console.log('Edit button not found!'));

        // This works - Start
            const [EditButton] = await page.$x('//table[contains(@class, "data-table")]//tbody//tr//a[contains(text(), "Edit") and contains(@data-user, "TestName") and contains(@data-user, "TestMail@test.com")]');

        if(EditButton) {
            console.log('Edit button is found!');
            await EditButton.click();
        } else throw new Error('Edit Button is not found!');
        // This works - End

        // This does not work - Start
        const [NameInputField] = await page.$x('//form[@id="edit-user-modal"]//fieldset//ul//li//input[@name="name"]');

        if (NameInputField) {
            await NameInputField.focus();
            await page.keyboard.type('New Test name', {delay: 1});
            console.log("Name input field is found!");
        } else {
            console.log("Name input field is not found!");
            await page.close();
        }
        // This does not work - End

        await sleep(10000);

        // This works
        await page.$eval('form#edit-user-modal > fieldset > ul > li > button', (e, n) => e.click());
    } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
    }
```

Second variant:

```
try {
        // Wait for the table
        await page.waitForXPath('//table[contains(@class, "data-table")]//tbody//tr//a[contains(text(), "Edit") and contains(@data-user, "TestName") and contains(@data-user, "TestMail@test.com")]')
            .catch(e => console.log('Edit button not found!'));

        // This works - Start
            const [EditButton] = await page.$x('//table[contains(@class, "data-table")]//tbody//tr//a[contains(text(), "Edit") and contains(@data-user, "TestName") and contains(@data-user, "TestMail@test.com")]');

        if(EditButton) {
            console.log('Edit button is found!');
            await EditButton.click();
        } else throw new Error('Edit Button is not found!');
        // This works - End

        // This does not work - Start
        await page.waitForSelector('form#edit-user-modal > fieldset > ul > li > input[name="name"]');

        await page.$eval('form#edit-user-modal > fieldset > ul > li > input[name="name"]', (e, n) => e.setAttribute('value', 'NewTestName'));
        await page.$eval('form#edit-user-modal > fieldset > ul > li > input[name="user"]', (e, n) => e.setAttribute('value', 'NewTestUser'));
        await page.$eval('form#edit-user-modal > fieldset > ul > li > input[name="pass"]', (e, n) => e.setAttribute('value', 'NewTestPassword'));
        await page.$eval('form#edit-user-modal > fieldset > ul > li > input[name="email"]', (e, n) => e.setAttribute('value', 'NewTestMail@test.com'));
        // This does not work - End

        await sleep(10000);

        // This works
        await page.$eval('form#edit-user-modal > fieldset > ul > li > button', (e, n) => e.click());
    } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
    }
```

Third Variant:

```
try {
        // Wait for the table
        await page.waitForXPath('//table[contains(@class, "data-table")]//tbody//tr//a[contains(text(), "Edit") and contains(@data-user, "TestName") and contains(@data-user, "TestMail@test.com")]')
            .catch(e => console.log('Edit button not found!'));

        // This works - Start
            const [EditButton] = await page.$x('//table[contains(@class, "data-table")]//tbody//tr//a[contains(text(), "Edit") and contains(@data-user, "TestName") and contains(@data-user, "TestMail@test.com")]');

        if(EditButton) {
            console.log('Edit button is found!');
            await EditButton.click();
        } else throw new Error('Edit Button is not found!');
        // This works - End

        // This does not work - Start
        await page.waitForSelector('form#edit-user-modal > fieldset > ul > li > input[name="name"]');
        await page.type('form#edit-user-modal > fieldset > ul > li > input[name="name"]', "New Test Name", {delay: 1});
        // This does not work - End

        await sleep(10000);

        // This works
        await page.$eval('form#edit-user-modal > fieldset > ul > li > button', (e, n) => e.click());
    } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
    }
```

Yesterday I when the XPath Method did not work for User addition, I have solved with $eval selector, but for user editing it does not work aswell.
I am following the documentation, the code seems to be ok. 
Can you help me to solve this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you can run js in page like this may be it helps you.

```
const result = await page.evaluate(_ => {
  const element = document.querySelector(`'form#edit-user-modal > fieldset > ul > li > input[name="name"]'`);
  if (element) {
    element.setAttribute('value', 'NewTestName');
  } else {
    return 'there is no element. maybe you need to wait until dom rendered and try again. or your selector is wrong?';
  }
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: document.querySelector(`'form#edit-user-modal > fieldset > ul > li > input[name="name"]'`); gives the following error: Error: Evaluation failed: DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Do
cument': ''form#edit-user-modal > fieldset > ul > li > input[name="name"]'' is n
ot a valid selector.

I have removed ' and ', but then it gives undefined as the result and value does not change at all.
I do not know why every single method fails to work.

Comment: puppeteer has non-headles mod so you can activate headless mode for development process. And  try your selectors. Also puppeteer has kind of max_waiting_limit. if the server is slow you need to increase this limit value.

Comment: const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
   headless: false,
   args: ['--headless'],
 }); //non-headless mode

Comment: await page.waitFor(30000);//wait 10 seconds to be sure page loaded

Comment: I already am running the Puppeteer in normal non-headless mode.
I have tried all of those queries manually via chrome dev tools and online real-time XPath testers, they are fine.
The page loads fine, I have tried with additional time as you have suggested, but it still does not work for some reason.

Comment: Take a breath and clean your code. Try to achive simple task. And use css selector instead of xpath because xpath is fragile. Send me the link of Page if you can.

Answer (score 0):

I have reinstalled puppeteer and cleared the NPM cache and magically somehow it started working. 
This is really strange.
I have also have added timeout with the value of 30000 (30 seconds) and proper error handling as you have suggested.
Thank you for your time and help.
If someone has the sample problem in the future, try clearing your NPM cache first, then remove node_modules and then install the modules again.
Also, add some the timeout and use await page.waitForSelector as I did.